# Looping through file contents and replacing values with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In a folder I have a list of CSV files where the top row looks like this:

```
HD,P00327971,20180816,,20180816,NoInvoice,18990.00,0,0
```

Note the bolded parts, the first is the PO and the second is where the invoice number should be.

I also have an invoice file with a list of invoices per PO that I was able to turn into an array in PowerShell that looks like this:

[image]

Here you can see a list of POs with an invoice number for each.

What I'd like to do is loop through each CSV file, grab that first row of contents, match the PO in it to the array I created and replace the text "NoInvoice" with the matching invoice from the invoice array.

Comment: Show us some more of these CSVs. Do they have column headers?

Comment: This is what they look like, the first row is kinda like the header row and then the rest contains the items on the shipment/invoice:  
HD,P00327971,20180816,,20180816,NoInvoice,18990.00,0,0  
PL,P00327971,82525521,,00007297891306609768,0,0  
PD,P00327971,Item1,123456789123,,1,949.500,0  
PL,P00327971,82525521,,00007297891306609782,0,0  
PD,P00327971,Item2,234567891234,,1,949.500,0  
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it would be easier to find the PO in the filenames instead of trying to work with the contents of each file so I set my output to include the PO in the filename and found it much easier to come up with a solution.

Below is the code I came up with:

```
#Get InvoiceRegister POs and Invoice Numbers
  $ColumnHeader = 
     (Get-Content 'S:\Common\EDI\user' |
      Select-Object -Skip 3 -First 1).Split(',')
  $Invoices =
     Import-CSV 'S:\Common\EDI\user' -Header $ColumnHeader | select cust_po, textbox362

#Filter Invoices
  $Invoices =
     $Invoices | where-object {$_.cust_po -like 'P*'}

#Get csv files
  $csvFiles = Get-ChildItem 'Z:\' -Filter *.csv

#Replace NoInvoice with matching PO
  ForEach($file in $csvFiles){
    $invoice = $invoices | Where-Object {$_.cust_po -eq ($file.name -split '_')[3]} | 
  Select-Object -First 1 -Property textbox362 | Select -ExpandProperty 'textbox362' | Out-String
    $invoice = $invoice -replace '\s',''
    (Get-Content $file).Replace('NoInvoice', $invoice) |
    Set-Content $file
    Clear-Variable invoice}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i guess you are not getting any clearer on this, so here's a try based on a few assumptions:

I gather your 'list of invoices file' is a csv file with headers `cust_po` and `Textbox362` which you can read in using `Import-Csv`.

Here I will fake that using

```
$poArray = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{cust_po = 'P00328431'; Textbox362 = 5233329}
    [pscustomobject]@{cust_po = 'P00336936'; Textbox362 = 5233331}
    [pscustomobject]@{cust_po = 'P00327971'; Textbox362 = 5233332}
)
```

Then there is a path where you have several csv files that need to be updated.

```
$path = "<YOUR PATH TO THE CSV FILES>"
```

Then I think something like this would work:

```
# read the csv files one by one as string arrays.
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $data = Get-Content $_.FullName
    # get the 'kinda' headers from the first row and split into array by delimiter comma
    $headers = $data[0] -split ','
    # check if these headers contain the string 'NoInvoice'
    if ($headers -contains 'NoInvoice') {
        # search array for the second value (item 1)
        $po = $poArray | Where-Object {$_.cust_po -eq $headers[1]}
        if ($po) {
            $headers[5] = $po.Textbox362   # the 6th element has the 'NoInvoice' text
            # recreate the header line
            $data[0] = $headers -join ','
            # create a new name for the updated file
            $fileDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)
            $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.FullName) + '_updated.csv'
            $newFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($fileDir,$fileName)  # or use Join-Path
            Set-Content -Path $newFile -Value $data -Force
            Write-Host "File $newFile created."
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "SKIPPED: Value $($headers[1]) not found in array for file $($_.Name)."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "SKIPPED: File $($_.Name) does not have the 'NoInvoice' value in its header."
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Theo,

Thank you very much for your input.  I was able to figure this out at the end of the day yesterday.

I figured it would be easier to find the PO in the filenames instead of trying to work with the contents of each file so I set my output to include the PO in the filename and found it much easier to come up with a solution.

Below is the code I came up with: